# Show that polynomial is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I am trying to prove that the polynomial $P = X^5 + X^2 + 1 ∈ F_2 [X]$ is irreducible.

What I did:

I showed that $X^2+X+1∈F_2[X]$ is the only irreducible polynomial of degree 2. Is there a way to use this to prove that $P$ is irreducible without checking all the polynomial products giving polynomials of degree $5$?

Many thanks!

Comment: Well, sure.  If you work $\pmod 2$ then either $P(x)$ has a root or it is divisible by the quadratic you mentioned.  (or it's  irreducible, of course).

Comment: The answer of JavaMan for degree $5$ is very instructive; see the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answers !

Answer (score 0):

Remark that if $P=Q_1Q_2$ the degree of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are different of $1$, then you can suppose that $Q_1=X^2+X+1$, but the roots of $X^2+X+1$ are third root of the unity, but a third root of the unity is not a root of $P$.

Comment: The OP asks for the polynomial over $\Bbb F_2$

Comment: one can deine root of unity over finite fields.

Comment: @Crostul The trick with third roots of unity still works. If $a^3=1$, then $a^5+a^2=2a^2=0$, so $a$ is not a zero of $P$. I refrain from upvoting this (correct) solution, because the question has been handled many times already.